# jQuery selector with single quote concatenation

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Im using jquery min 1.3.2. Could you help me to fix jQuery selector? It doesn't work with single quote user name. If user = "Peter", everything works OK.

```
var user = "Pet'e";
var id = "1";

var value = $("a[name=" + user + "][id=" + id + "]").attr("todo");
```

Comment: this doesnot make sense.. since you already have an id **(note: id should always be unique)**.. you don't need name attribute selector there at all.. and yes avoid using (just) integer as ids..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the value in `""`

```
var value = $('a[name="' + user + '"][id="' + id + '"]').attr("todo");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8MFCx/)

but since you have a id use id selector

```
$('#' + id)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DWJJD/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the ' character:

```
var user = "Pet'e";
var id = "1";
var userEscaped = user.replace("'", "\\'");

var value = $("a[name=" + user + "][id=" + id + "]").attr("todo");
```

Answer (score 1):

try escaping

```
var user = "Pet\'e";
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a `unique id` and try it like,

```
var value = $('a#' + id).attr('todo');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already assigned the `id` for your element, you just need to use:

```
$('#' + id)
```

Beside that, seem like you're using `data` attribute for `todo`, so change:

```
$('#' + id).attr("todo")
```

to:

```
$('#' + id).data("todo")
```

or:

```
$(this).attr("data-todo")
```